# How can I install PostGIS to Mac Osx ? (I always get "brew link libpng libtiff proj" error)

Tags: macos, homebrew, postgis

I tried to install "gdal" or "PostGIS" to my Mac OSX  from homebrew but I've got an error "brew link libpng libtiff proj".

When I tried to "brew linklibpng", I've got an error:

```
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man3/libpng.3
```

I've also tried 'brew update', uninstall and install "libpng libtiff proj" but there is always problem as:

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
       The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
        Could not symlink share/man/man3/libpng.3
       /usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable.
```

What's the problem there?

```
$ brew install gdal
$ Error: You must `brew link libpng libtiff proj` before gdal can be installed 
$ brew link libpng
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.19... 
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man3/libpng.3
       /usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable.
```

Comment: How about `sudo chmod +w /usr/local/man/man3` (or maybe chown)?

Comment: Thanks @Seth..:) **sudo chown [username] /usr/local/share/man/man3** is working..

Comment: You might have `sudo brew install`-ed at some point, which would have screwed up the ownership.